# Bind Default value to Combox from OData response

Tags: sapui5

I'm new to UI5 and trying to make a change in the existing code written 3 years ago by someone. I want to add a default value to a combo box before the view is displayed to user. My problem is, View gets loaded without showing default value. Could you please suggest how to display a default value before user changes the selection? I want to add first KOSTL field, if there is any, from Odata responsive. I tried something like below and put it in "dynamicData" function below. But it doesn't work.

In Odata, a List of cost centers are being fetched using mCostCenter Model by supplying the logged on user as input. We need to display first KOSTL value in drop down if the result is not blank.

var oData = this.getView().getModel("mCostCenter").getData();

sap.ui.getCore().byId("idDropdown1").setSelectedKey(OData.results[0].Kostl);

Drop Down:

![Drop Down][1]

View code:

var oDropdownBox1 = new sap.m.ComboBox(this.createId("idDropdown1"), {

```
        //items:[oItemTemplate1]

        maxWidth: "100%",

        placeholder: "Select Cost Center to continue",

        selectionChange: jQuery.proxy(oController.onDropdownPress, this.getController()),

        items: {

            path: "mCostCenter>/",

            template: new sap.ui.core.ListItem({

                key: "{mCostCenter>Kostl}",

                text: "{mCostCenter>Ltext}"

            })

        }

    }).addStyleClass("idDropdown1");
```

Controller Code:

```
onInit: function() {

    var oUserData = {};

    var y = "/sap/bc/ui2/start_up";

    var xmlHttp = null;

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {

            oUserData = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);

            //console.log(oUserData);

        }

    };

    xmlHttp.open("GET", y, false);

    xmlHttp.send(null);

    //oUserData.id = "nouser";

    this.currUser = oUserData.id;

    //new code for URL

    this.sUrl = "https://ZZZ.ZZZ.com:8443/"; //default value

    if (window.cordova && sap.Logon) {

        sap.Logon.core.getContext(jQuery.proxy(conSuccess, this), conError);

        function conSuccess(objContext) {

            if (objContext.registrationContext) {

                var context = objContext.registrationContext;

                if (context.https) {

                    this.sUrl = "https://" + context.serverHost + ":" + context.serverPort + "/";

                } else {

                    this.sUrl = "http://" + context.serverHost + ":" + context.serverPort + "/";

                }

            }

            //call data now

            if (oUserData.id == null) {

                sap.m.MessageToast.show("Error fetching user. Please contact Administrator.");

            } else {

                //sap.m.MessageToast.show("User is: "+oUserData.id);

                this.dynamicData();

            }

        }

        function conError(errorInfo) {

            //default value will be used

            //call data now with default

            if (oUserData.id == null) {

                sap.m.MessageToast.show("Error fetching user. Please contact Administrator.");

            } else {

                //sap.m.MessageToast.show("User is: "+oUserData.id);

                this.dynamicData();

            }

        }

    } else {

        if (window.location && window.location.hostname != "localhost") {

            this.sUrl = "https://" + window.location.hostname + ":" + window.location.port + "/";

        }

        //call data now

        if (oUserData.id == null) {

            sap.m.MessageToast.show("Error fetching user. Please contact Administrator.");

        } else {

            //sap.m.MessageToast.show("User is: "+oUserData.id);

            this.dynamicData();

        }

    }

    //new code URL end here

    /*if(oUserData.id == null){



        sap.m.MessageToast.show("Error fetching user. Please contact Administrator.");



    } else {



        //sap.m.MessageToast.show("User is: "+oUserData.id);



        this.dynamicData();



    }*/

},

onDropdownPress: function(evt) {

    //alert("hi");

    //alert(JSON.stringify(evt.getSource().getBindingContext()));

    //      debugger;

    var selString = null;

    //var selText = evt.getSource().getSelectedItem();

    var selString1 = evt.getSource().getSelectedKey();

    var oData = this.getView().getModel("mCostCenter").getData();

    for (var i = 0; i < oData.length; i++) {

        if (oData[i].Kostl == selString1) {

            selString = parseFloat(oData[i].AvBubdget).toFixed(2) /*+ oData[i].Ltext*/ ;

            break;

        }

    }

    var dataJSModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

    dataJSModel.setData({
        "selD": selString,
        "IDSel": selString1
    });

    this.getView().setModel(dataJSModel, "mCostSel");

    var jsonData = this.getView().getModel("mfullReportees").getData();

    var reportees = {

        value: []

    };

    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {

        if (jsonData[i].Kostl == selString1) {

            if (reportees.value.length == 0) {

                //new Date(data.results[i]["SUBMISSION_DATE"].match(/\d+/)[0] * 1)

                if (jsonData[i].Begda && jsonData[i].Endda) {

                    var begdate = new Date(jsonData[i].Begda.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);

                    var enddate = new Date(jsonData[i].Endda.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);

                    var today = new Date();

                    if (today >= begdate && enddate >= today) {

                        reportees.value.push({

                            "ImUser": jsonData[i].ImUser,

                            "Pernr": jsonData[i].Pernr,

                            "Endda": jsonData[i].Endda,

                            "Begda": jsonData[i].Begda,

                            "Kostl": jsonData[i].Kostl

                        });

                    }

                } else {

                    reportees.value.push({

                        "ImUser": jsonData[i].ImUser,

                        "Pernr": jsonData[i].Pernr,

                        "Endda": jsonData[i].Endda,

                        "Begda": jsonData[i].Begda,

                        "Kostl": jsonData[i].Kostl

                    });

                }

            } else {

                for (var k = 0; k < reportees.value.length; k++) {

                    if (reportees.value[k]["Pernr"] == jsonData[i].Pernr) {

                        break;

                    } else if (k == (reportees.value.length - 1)) {

                        /*reportees.value.push({



                                    "ImUser": jsonData[i].ImUser,



                                    "Pernr": jsonData[i].Pernr,



                                    "Endda": jsonData[i].Endda,



                                    "Begda": jsonData[i].Begda,



                                    "Kostl": jsonData[i].Kostl



                                });*/

                        if (jsonData[i].Begda && jsonData[i].Endda) {

                            var begdate = new Date(jsonData[i].Begda.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);

                            var enddate = new Date(jsonData[i].Endda.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);

                            var today = new Date();

                            if (today >= begdate && enddate >= today) {

                                reportees.value.push({

                                    "ImUser": jsonData[i].ImUser,

                                    "Pernr": jsonData[i].Pernr,

                                    "Endda": jsonData[i].Endda,

                                    "Begda": jsonData[i].Begda,

                                    "Kostl": jsonData[i].Kostl

                                });

                            }

                        } else {

                            reportees.value.push({

                                "ImUser": jsonData[i].ImUser,

                                "Pernr": jsonData[i].Pernr,

                                "Endda": jsonData[i].Endda,

                                "Begda": jsonData[i].Begda,

                                "Kostl": jsonData[i].Kostl

                            });

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

    var dataJSModel1 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

    dataJSModel1.setData(reportees);

    this.getView().setModel(dataJSModel1, "mReportees");

    var empData = this.getView().getModel("mfullResults").getData();

    var employees = {

        value: []

    };

    var reporteeslen = dataJSModel1.oData.value.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < empData.length; i++) {

        for (var j = 0; j < reporteeslen; j++) {

            if (empData[i].Pernr == dataJSModel1.oData.value[j].Pernr) {

                employees.value.push(empData[i]);

            }

        }

    }

    var dataJSModel2 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

    dataJSModel2.setData(employees);

    this.getView().setModel(dataJSModel2, "mEmployees");

    this.onSelectionChange();

},

    getselectedfn: function(evt) {

    //      debugger;

    sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.show(0);

    var contexts = sap.ui.getCore().byId("idTable").getSelectedContexts();

    var items = contexts.map(function(c) {

        return c.getObject();

    });

    //alert(JSON.stringify(items)); - only one item

    var ApprovedBudget = parseFloat(this.getView().getModel("mCostSel").getData().selD);

    var selectedCC = this.getView().getModel("mCostSel").getData().IDSel;

    //alert(ApprovedBudget);

    /*if(ApprovedBudget < parseFloat(items[0].Amount)){



                sap.m.MessageBox.alert("Selected amount is higher than budget", {



                    title: "Not enough budget" 



                });



                return;



            }*/

    //var sUrl = "https://ZZZ.ZZZ.com:8443/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZMOB_HCM_OVERTIME_SRV/";

    var sUrl = this.sUrl + "sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZMOB_HCM_OVERTIME_SRV/";

    var oHeaders = {};

    oHeaders['Authorization'] = "Basic " + btoa("nouser:nopass");

    oHeaders['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = "FETCH";

    oHeaders['Accept'] = "application/json";

    var request =

        {

            headers: oHeaders,

            requestUri: sUrl,

            method: "GET"

        };

    OData.read(request, jQuery.proxy(readSuccessCallback, this), errorCallback);

    function readSuccessCallback(data, response)

    {

        header_xcsrf_token = response.headers['x-csrf-token'];

        //oHeaders['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = header_xcsrf_token;

        var oHeaders = {

            "X-CSRF-TOKEN": header_xcsrf_token, //most js frameworks use this to identify ajax request.

            //  "Content-Type" : "application/atom+xml",

            //  "Content-Type" : "multipart/mixed; boundary=batch",

            //  "Accept" : "application/atom+xml"

        };

        //var sUrl = "https://ZZZ.ZZZ.com:8443/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZMOB_HCM_OVERTIME_SRV/ET_OT2_Action('"+this.currUser+"')";

        var sUrl = this.sUrl + "sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZMOB_HCM_OVERTIME_SRV/";

        //ET_OT2_Action('"+this.currUser+"')

        var approvalChanges = [];

        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sUrl, true, null, null, oHeaders);

        //beginning for loop

        //             debugger;

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

            var iworkdate = new Date(items[i].Workdate.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);

            var strWorkDate = iworkdate.toISOString();

            strWorkDate = strWorkDate.substring(0, (strWorkDate.length - 2));

            var iCreatedon = new Date(items[i].Createdon.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);

            var strCreatedon = iCreatedon.toISOString();

            strCreatedon = strCreatedon.substring(0, (strCreatedon.length - 2));

            var data2 = {
                "ImAction": "APPROVE",

                "ImAvailableBudget": ApprovedBudget.toString(),

                "ImReason": "",

                "ImUser": items[i].ImUser,

                "Pernr": items[i].Pernr,

                "Workdate": strWorkDate,

                "Awart": items[i].Awart,

                "Counter": items[i].Counter,

                "Catshours": items[i].Catshours,

                "Meinh": items[i].Meinh,

                "Status": items[i].Status,

                "Createdby": items[i].Createdby,

                "Createdon": strCreatedon,

                "Createdat": items[i].Createdat,

                "Name": items[i].Name,

                "Atext": items[i].Atext,

                "Grade": items[i].Grade,

                "Shift": items[i].Shift,

                "Versl": items[i].Versl,

                "OtCompensation": items[i].OtCompensation,

                "Amount": items[i].Amount,

                "Waers": items[i].Waers,

                "Gjahr": items[i].Gjahr,

                "Period": items[i].Period,

                "Kostl": selectedCC

            };

            var jsonrequest = {

                "d": data2

            };

            ApprovedBudget = ApprovedBudget - parseFloat(items[i].Amount);

            //alert(JSON.stringify(items));

            var sPathApproval = "ET_OT2_Action('" + this.currUser + "')";

            //var sPathApproval = "ET_OT2_Action('abapdev4')";

            jsonrequest["d"]["__metadata"] =

            {
                "uri": sUrl,

                "type": "ZMOB_HCM_OVERTIME_SRV.ET_OT2_ACTION"
            };

            approvalChanges.push(oModel.createBatchOperation(sPathApproval, "PUT", jsonrequest));

        }

        oModel.addBatchChangeOperations(approvalChanges);

        //end of for loop

        //              debugger;

        oModel.submitBatch(jQuery.proxy(function(oData, oResponse, aErrorResponses) {

                //               debugger;

                var count = 0;

                //               if (typeof(oData.__batchResponses[0].__changeResponses[i]) === 'undefined' && typeof(oData.__batchResponses[0].response.statusCode)!=='undefined')

                //                   {

                //                   

                //                   

                //                       var message = "Please contact Administrator";

                //

                //                   

                //                  sap.m.MessageBox.alert(message, {

                //

                //                        title: "Error occurred" 

                //

                //                    });

                //                   

                //                   

                //              }

                if (aErrorResponses.length > 0) {

                    var errMsg = JSON.parse(oData.__batchResponses[0].response.body).error.message.value;

                    sap.m.MessageBox.alert(errMsg, {

                        title: "Error ocurred",

                        icon: sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.ERROR,

                    });

                } else {

                    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

                        debugger;

                        if (typeof(oData.__batchResponses[0].__changeResponses) !== 'undefined' && oData.__batchResponses[0].__changeResponses[i].statusCode ===
                            "204")

                        {

                            count = count + 1;

                        }

                    }

                    sap.m.MessageBox.alert(count + " out of " + items.length + " records has been approved.", {

                        title: "Overtime has been approved successfully",

                        icon: sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.SUCCESS,

                    });

                }

                //               if(typeof(oData.__batchResponses[0].response.statusCode) !== 'undefined' && oData.__batchResponses[0].response.statusCode==="500"){

                //                   

                //               }

                this.dynamicData();

            }, this),

            function(e) {

                //                  debugger;

                //alert("Error occurred", err); 

                var message = "Please contact Administrator";

                if (e.response && e.response.body) {

                    // var obj =  JSON.parse(e.response.body);

                    // if(obj.error && obj.error.message && obj.error.message.value){

                    message = e.response.body; //obj.error.message.value;

                    // }

                }

                sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.hide();

                sap.m.MessageBox.alert(message, {

                    title: "Error occurred",

                    icon: sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.ERROR

                });

            }

        );

        //              var newrequest =

        //

        //              {

        //

        //              headers : oHeaders,

        //

        //              requestUri : sUrl,

        //

        //              method : "PUT",

        //

        //              data : jsonrequest

        //

        //              };

        //

        //    

        //

        //              OData.read(newrequest,jQuery.proxy(readSuccessCallbackPOST,this), errorCallbackPOST);

    }

    function errorCallback(e)

    {

        sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.hide();

        sap.m.MessageBox.alert("Server not reachable", {

            title: "Please try again later",

            icon: sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.ERROR

        });

    }

    function errorCallbackPOST(e)

    {

        //.indexOf("Remote function call module exception") != -1)

        var message = "Please contact Administrator";

        if (e.response && e.response.body) {

            var obj = JSON.parse(e.response.body);

            if (obj.error && obj.error.message && obj.error.message.value) {

                message = obj.error.message.value;

            }

        }

        sap.m.MessageBox.alert(message, {

            title: "Error occurred",

            icon: sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.ERROR

        });

    }

    function readSuccessCallbackPOST(data, response) {

        //var app = this.nav.getView().app;

        sap.m.MessageBox.alert("Approved", {

            title: "Overtime has been approved successfully",

            icon: sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.SUCCESS

        });

        this.dynamicData();

    }

},

dynamicData: function() {

    //var sURL = "https://ZZZ.ZZZ.com:8443/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZMOB_HCM_OVERTIME_SRV/ET_OT2_CostCenters?$filter=ImUser eq '"+this.currUser+"'";

    sap.ui.getCore().byId("idApprove").setEnabled(false);

    sap.ui.getCore().byId("idReject").setEnabled(false);

    var sURL = this.sUrl + "sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZMOB_HCM_OVERTIME_SRV/ET_OT2_CostCenters?$filter=ImUser eq '" + this.currUser + "'";

    var oHeaders = {};

    oHeaders['Authorization'] = "Basic " + btoa("nouser:nopass");

    oHeaders['contentType'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';

    sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.show(0);

    var request = {

        headers: oHeaders,

        requestUri: sURL,

        method: "GET"

    };

    OData.read(request, jQuery.proxy(readSuccessCallback, this), errorCallback);

    /*sURL = " https://ZZZ.ZZZ.com:8443/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZMOB_HCM_OVERTIME_SRV/ET_ot_repSet?$filter=ImUser eq '"+this.currUser+"'";



    request['requestUri'] = sURL;



    OData.read(request, jQuery.proxy(readSuccessCallback1,this), errorCallback);



    sURL = "https://ZZZ.ZZZ.com:8443/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZMOB_HCM_OVERTIME_SRV/ET_ot_resultSet?$filter=ImUser eq '"+this.currUser+"'";



    request['requestUri'] = sURL;



    OData.read(request, jQuery.proxy(readSuccessCallback2,this), errorCallback);*/

    function readSuccessCallback(data, response) {

        this.boolNoCostCenter = false;

        this.boolNoReportees = false;

        this.boolNoActivePeriod = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {

            if (data.results[i].Kostl == "ERR_CC") {

                this.boolNoCostCenter = true;

                data.results.splice(i, 1);

                i = i - 1;

                //sap.m.MessageBox.error("There are no cost centers assigned against your user.");

                continue; //continue to remove other erros from the array

            }

            if (data.results[i].Kostl == "ERR_REP") {

                this.boolNoReportees = true;

                data.results.splice(i, 1);

                i = i - 1;

                //sap.m.MessageBox.error("There are no cost centers assigned against your user.");

                continue;

            }

            if (data.results[i].Kostl == "ERR_PAY") {

                this.boolNoActivePeriod = true;

                data.results.splice(i, 1);

                i = i - 1;

                //sap.m.MessageBox.error("There are no cost centers assigned against your user.");

                continue;

            }

        }

        if (this.boolNoCostCenter) {

            sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.hide();

            sap.m.MessageBox.alert("There are no cost centers assigned against your user.", {

                icon: sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.WARNING

            });

        } else if (this.boolNoReportees) {

            sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.hide();

            sap.m.MessageBox.alert("There are no reportees against your user.", {

                icon: sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.WARNING

            });

        } else if (this.boolNoActivePeriod) {

            sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.hide();

            sap.m.MessageBox.alert("Payroll is in progress. Overtime Approval is closed for the month", {

                icon: sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.WARNING

            });

        } else {

            //go ahead and read

            //sURL = "https://ZZZ.ZZZ.com:8443/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZMOB_HCM_OVERTIME_SRV/ET_OT2_Reportees?$filter=ImUser eq '"+this.currUser+"'";

            sURL = this.sUrl + "sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZMOB_HCM_OVERTIME_SRV/ET_OT2_Reportees?$filter=ImUser eq '" + this.currUser + "'";

            request['requestUri'] = sURL;

            OData.read(request, jQuery.proxy(readSuccessCallback1, this), errorCallback);

            //sURL = "https://ZZZ.ZZZ.com:8443/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZMOB_HCM_OVERTIME_SRV/ET_OT2_OvertimeRecords?$filter=ImUser eq '"+this.currUser+"'";

            sURL = this.sUrl + "sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZMOB_HCM_OVERTIME_SRV/ET_OT2_OvertimeRecords?$filter=ImUser eq '" + this.currUser + "'";

            request['requestUri'] = sURL;

            OData.read(request, jQuery.proxy(readSuccessCallback2, this), errorCallback);

        }

        //console.log("json result " + JSON.stringify(data.results));

        var dataJSModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

        dataJSModel.setData(data.results);

        this.getView().setModel(dataJSModel, "mCostCenter");

        //sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.hide();

    }

    function readSuccessCallback1(data, response) {

        var dataJSModel1 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

        dataJSModel1.setData(data.results);

        this.getView().setModel(dataJSModel1, "mfullReportees");

        //sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.hide(); 

    }

    function readSuccessCallback2(data, response) {

        var dataJSModel1 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

        dataJSModel1.setData(data.results);

        this.getView().setModel(dataJSModel1, "mfullResults");

        var selString1 = this.getView().byId("idDropdown1").getSelectedKey();

        if (selString1 != "" && selString1 != null) {

            var oData = this.getView().getModel("mCostCenter").getData();

            for (var i = 0; i < oData.length; i++) {

                if (oData[i].Kostl == selString1) {

                    selString = parseFloat(oData[i].AvBubdget).toFixed(2) /*+ oData[i].Ltext*/ ;

                    break;

                }

            }

            var dataJSModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

            dataJSModel.setData({
                "selD": selString,
                "IDSel": selString1
            });

            this.getView().setModel(dataJSModel, "mCostSel");

            var jsonData = this.getView().getModel("mfullReportees").getData();

            var reportees = {

                value: []

            };

            for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {

                if (jsonData[i].Kostl == selString1) {

                    if (reportees.value.length == 0) {

                        /*reportees.value.push({



                                            "ImUser": jsonData[i].ImUser,



                                            "Pernr": jsonData[i].Pernr,



                                            "Endda": jsonData[i].Endda,



                                            "Begda": jsonData[i].Begda,



                                            "Kostl": jsonData[i].Kostl



                                        });*/

                        if (jsonData[i].Begda && jsonData[i].Endda) {

                            var begdate = new Date(jsonData[i].Begda.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);

                            var enddate = new Date(jsonData[i].Endda.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);

                            var today = new Date();

                            if (today >= begdate && enddate >= today) {

                                reportees.value.push({

                                    "ImUser": jsonData[i].ImUser,

                                    "Pernr": jsonData[i].Pernr,

                                    "Endda": jsonData[i].Endda,

                                    "Begda": jsonData[i].Begda,

                                    "Kostl": jsonData[i].Kostl

                                });

                            }

                        } else {

                            reportees.value.push({

                                "ImUser": jsonData[i].ImUser,

                                "Pernr": jsonData[i].Pernr,

                                "Endda": jsonData[i].Endda,

                                "Begda": jsonData[i].Begda,

                                "Kostl": jsonData[i].Kostl

                            });

                        }

                    } else {

                        for (var k = 0; k < reportees.value.length; k++) {

                            if (reportees.value[k]["Pernr"] == jsonData[i].Pernr) {

                                break;

                            } else if (k == (reportees.value.length - 1)) {

                                /*reportees.value.push({



                                                    "ImUser": jsonData[i].ImUser,



                                                    "Pernr": jsonData[i].Pernr,



                                                    "Endda": jsonData[i].Endda,



                                                    "Begda": jsonData[i].Begda,



                                                    "Kostl": jsonData[i].Kostl



                                                });*/

                                if (jsonData[i].Begda && jsonData[i].Endda) {

                                    var begdate = new Date(jsonData[i].Begda.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);

                                    var enddate = new Date(jsonData[i].Endda.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);

                                    var today = new Date();

                                    if (today >= begdate && enddate >= today) {

                                        reportees.value.push({

                                            "ImUser": jsonData[i].ImUser,

                                            "Pernr": jsonData[i].Pernr,

                                            "Endda": jsonData[i].Endda,

                                            "Begda": jsonData[i].Begda,

                                            "Kostl": jsonData[i].Kostl

                                        });

                                    }

                                } else {

                                    reportees.value.push({

                                        "ImUser": jsonData[i].ImUser,

                                        "Pernr": jsonData[i].Pernr,

                                        "Endda": jsonData[i].Endda,

                                        "Begda": jsonData[i].Begda,

                                        "Kostl": jsonData[i].Kostl

                                    });

                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

            /*for(var i=0; i<jsonData.length; i++){



                            if(jsonData[i].Kostl == selString1){



                                reportees.value.push({



                                    "ImUser": jsonData[i].ImUser,



                                    "Pernr": jsonData[i].Pernr,



                                    "Endda": jsonData[i].Endda,



                                    "Begda": jsonData[i].Begda,



                                    "Kostl": jsonData[i].Kostl



                                });



                                }



                            };*/

            var dataJSModel1 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

            dataJSModel1.setData(reportees);

            this.getView().setModel(dataJSModel1, "mReportees");

            var empData = this.getView().getModel("mfullResults").getData();

            var employees = {

                value: []

            };

            var reporteeslen = dataJSModel1.oData.value.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < empData.length; i++) {

                for (var j = 0; j < reporteeslen; j++) {

                    if (empData[i].Pernr == dataJSModel1.oData.value[j].Pernr)

                        employees.value.push(empData[i]);

                }

            }

            var dataJSModel2 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

            dataJSModel2.setData(employees);

            this.getView().setModel(dataJSModel2, "mEmployees");

        }

        sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.hide();

    }

    function errorCallback(e) {

        sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.hide();

        //alert("An error occurred ");

        if (e.response.statusCode == "400" && e.response.body.indexOf("Remote function call module exception") != -1) {

            sap.m.MessageToast.show("You have no Cost Center or Reportees assigned. Kindly check");

        } else if (e.response.statusCode == "403" || e.response.statusCode == "0") {

            sap.m.MessageToast.show("Server not reachable. Please try again later");

        } else if(e.response && e.response.body) {
            var message = "Please contact Administrator";

            var obj = JSON.parse(e.response.body);

            if (obj.error && obj.error.message && obj.error.message.value) {

                message = obj.error.message.value;

            }

            sap.m.MessageToast.show(message);

        }  else {

            sap.m.MessageToast.show("An error occurred. Please contact administrator");

        }

        console.log("An error occurred " + JSON.stringify(e));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, once you have the data you should do something similar to this:

```
var defaultItem = this.getView().byId("idDropdown1").getItems()[0]; 
this.getView().byId("idDropdown1").setSelectedItem(defaultItem, true);
```

this will get the first element in the model and then set it as the selected element in your ComboBox.

In this example it set as selected item the first of the ComboBox.